# AmCharts when click, add a custom balloon

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts

I'm trying to set a balloon when the user click in some point of the graphic, like it happens when you set an guide.

Something like this:
[image]

The problem is that on hover out, the balloon hides. And when I click, I don't know how to get the value of that point to shows in balloon.

Someone already made something like this?

Comment: There isn't a way to lock a balloon position as they are meant to only appear on hover. You can use a trend line to create a marker on a specific point to call it out and perhaps add a label with extra information like in [this example](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-trend-lines-to-mark-special-events-on-chart/). Also note the [clickGraphItem](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#clickGraphItem) event gives you everything about the point that was clicked, so you can use it to dynamically set the position and label with info about the point.

Comment: Thanks @xorspark! Unfortunately the label field is too limitated https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Label. I can't set background for example

Comment: FYI - wrong label link as the demo is using the graph's `labelText` property. Still, the limitation exists there as well.You could possibly modify the SVG post trendline insertion through the `drawn` event similar to how [this demo](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/adding-bordered-boxes-fill-color-graph-value-labels/) does it. You'll need to set `addClassNames` to true to query the graph labels through `querySelectorAll`. It's still pretty limited though.

Comment: Indeed, the link is wrong, the correct one [is this](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide#label). With [the demo](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/adding-bordered-boxes-fill-color-graph-value-labels/) you passed, I added [the box](https://ibb.co/jbBNxp). Now I have to control the synced events to add the box and guides to the other graphics.